# How to automate showing Sarif output of custom tool

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks, sarif

I have a (python) tool which can produce multiple output formats. I am currently running this tool in VSCode as a user task with a problem matcher. The tool can also produce SARIF output. I would like to migrate the tool to only use SARIF. What is the easiest way to run a script and display the output in VSCode without additional manual steps.

I have checked the Microsoft Sarif plugin API but only a JS API appears to be available.